# Meaning of だまって置いてきちゃお

Tags: meaning, colloquial-language, manga

I'm reading a Shin Chan strip and he and his friends are discussing who is going to take care of the stray dog they found.  One by one he asks his friends, and they all say they can't.  Then, he says (without looking at his last friend)

> そうだ！！マサオ*んち*だまって置{お}いてきちゃお。

Then, his friend, who is next to him, says:

> ボクいるんだけど・・・

So, in the first sentences, I don't get the **だまって** (no idea what it is) or the **置いてきちゃお**.  I know 置く as an auxiliary verb to say you're doing something in preparation for something else, but I don't understand it in that context, with きちゃお after it's て form.

Would be very thankful if somebody could explain to me the use of each of those expressions in the sentence.

Here's a pic of the panel itself:

[image: Panel]

Comment: What are you trying to tell by italicized んち?

Comment: Just pointing out what I edited

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice it because that part of edit history was folded up :)

Answer (score 3):

You sure you're quoting their lines correctly?  I haven't read the strip or seen the TV episode but found a similar dialog, in which Masao happened to be that last friend Shin-chan didn't ask:

同じまさおくんネタなんですが
初めてシロが登場したシーンで
捨て犬だったシロをどうするか４人で考えてる時

しん　｢そうだ! 黙ってまさおくんちに置いて来ちゃおうか｣
まさ　｢僕いるんだけど…」
が最高に笑えました!

http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1240826137

Shin: "Oh, I know.  How about leaving it at Masao's house without telling him?"
Masa: "Um... I'm here."

・（X に）黙って: without telling (X)  / 黙る: to hush up, shut one's mouth
・まさおくんち = まさおくん+の+うち  （cf. 先生んち、俺んとこ、あんたんとこ, etc.)
・置く in 置いてきちゃおうか here is NOT an auxiliary verb but part of the verbal combination 置いてくる "go and leave" (lit. "leave and come back").
・きちゃおうか = きてしまおうか The use of 完了形 てしまう conveys not so much the sense of completion as the daring aspect of his mischievous act (given moral  objections, risks, etc.).

Comment: There was a small mistake in the first sentence, I corrected it.  But overall it's straight from the original volume 1, page 54 (original version)

Comment: The small fix does make a pretty big difference (incomprehensible -> comprehensible).

Answer (score 0):

Vしゃお→Vしちゃおう
The meaning is "Let's V "

しちゃう＝してしまう
しちゃおう＝してしまおう